# "Segmentation Fault" being thrown by third party package. How to prevent it from displaying on console?

Tags: python

Pretty self-explanatory from the title.  I'm using PyQt4 to crawl pages and I occasionally get a SegFault error.

The overall program seems to still be working regardless though, so all I want to do is prevent that "Segmentation Fault (core dumped)" error from being shown on the console.  How is this done?

Comment: Can you show the command line you're using to run PyQt4? And what platform are you on? "Segmentation Fault" is not printed by python, it's printed by whatever shell you're using to run the program, so the solution will be there.

Comment: Ahh ok.  I'm using Ubuntu and Python 2.7

Comment: Still need the command line you're using :)

Comment: Redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null` *when launching the process.*

Comment: Have you reported this error to the PyQt team?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segmentation Fault is an system error, which occurs when your program tries to access wrong memory address. It is internal program problem and you cannot continue process. It could be possible, but believe me, you should not. So, you should fix it.

To fix it, you should dig into Qt internals, but I'd like to suggest you to install fresh library version and make sure you have latest packages.